# Split a string after a certain variable in .NET Core

Tags: .net, string, split

I'm new to .net and is facing a problem.
I have an image url in the form of string:
"https://reechhubstorage.blob.core.windows.net/60d9cd90070ff8cd3cad08cc/product/637979716879989319debby-hudson-HxtrSNpRRz8-unsplash.jpg"

The "product" in this string is the folder name and it can vary.
What I want is to split the above url and get everything after the "folder name". I have tried to use sub strings but I think I'm doing it wrong:

```
int i = FileUrl.IndexOf(data.FolderName);
string imageUrl = FileUrl.Split(data.FolderName)[1];
```

Comment: Use the System.IO.Path class.

Comment: already using this

Comment: Start by reading through this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split

Comment: Read this, but it doesn't give any solid answer